# How to control arduino robot by android app over Internet?

Tags: android, arduino

I am thinking to make an robot based on arduino and that should be controlled by an Android app so how can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is going to be rejected. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: If I get any referral link for this that also going to be helpful

Comment: Asking for tutorials, links, code or any other extra-site resources is off-topic. Mind that this is not a Google replacement.

Answer (score 0):

purchase an ESP8266 WiFi Module (easy to use and low of cost) for arduino. develop an Andriod App in which you have to send commands to esp8266. read these commmands from esp8266 through arduino and actuate motors of robot.